# Vim match multiple lines and substitute on each line

Tags: vim, substitution

I have a file like this:

```
# For testing                                                                                                           
Space 5 ;
Width 8 ;
Length 10 ;
" ;

# normal line
Space 5 ;
Width 8 ;
Length 10 ;
" ;


# For testing
Space 5 ;
Width 8 ;
Length 10 ;
" ;
```

I'm trying to comment out every lines between `# For testing` and `" ;`.

I knew I can match this pattern by command `# For testing\\_.\\{-}" ;`, but how can I replace the content of each line and append a `#` as prefix at each line?

I would like to have something like this after substitution:

```
# For testing                                                                                                           #Space 5 ;
#Width 8 ;
#Length 10 ;
#" ;

# normal line
Space 5 ;
Width 8 ;
Length 10 ;
" ;


# For testing
#Space 5 ;
#Width 8 ;
#Length 10 ;
#" ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the solution given by @ruohola:

```
:g/^# For testing/+1,/^"/ norm! I#
```

Comment: Didn't know about using a search pattern in a range, nice!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary), you can use:

```
:g/^# For testing/+1,/^" ;/Commentary
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external command such as awk

```
:%!awk '/For testing/,/^"/ {print "\# "$0;next}1' %
```

This command replaces the entire file with the output of the awk command. We need to escape "#" in the awk command to prevent vim from replacing it with the "alternate file"